# Share Point Foundation 2010 - Configuration Failed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, database-connection

We got a Share Point 2010 farm here on my company but we were victims of a ramsonware and lost a server. I was incubated of prepare a new VM and reinstall the SP (I never had any kind of contact with SP installation).

I downloaded the SharePoint Foundation 2010 from Microsoft and installed it (I chose "Server-Farm" option and then "Complete").

[image: Selected install options]

After it, on the wizard, I connected to our SP config database, chose a Passphrase. On Advanced Settings I marked "Use this machine to host the web site".

... Finally I got this error message.

[image: (Failed to connect to the configuration database)]

*Solution attempt:*

I found up on config database that previous SP installation was on 14.0.7015.1000. I downloaded this specific patch but it did not affect my SP 'cause it was on a newer version. Can I download a specific SP version somewhere? And... Is this my problem or I'm losing my time?

```
Used query:
    SELECT TOP 1000 [VersionId]
          ,[Version]
          ,[Id]
          ,[UserName]
          ,[TimeStamp]
          ,[FinalizeTimeStamp]
          ,[Mode]
          ,[ModeStack]
          ,[Updates]
          ,[Notes]
      FROM [SPServer2010_Config].[dbo].[Versions]
```

I got a Windows Server 2012 R2 as a database server and I'm trying to install the SP on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (same operating system used on the old infected machine).

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

With THIS [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983) - provided by @James Grizzle - I was able to install the right version, but the error persists.
Trying to overcome the situation I installed a new instance o Share Point, with a new config database, and I'm trying to change the config database to the original one. Is it possible? Setting the content db only seems not to be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****EDIT 2********
Your error states

> The license state for the current server doesn't match the farm's license state.

This suggests to me that you have an incorrect edition of SharePoint installed, like you are trying to add a SharePoint Foundation server to a SharePoint Server Standard (or Enterprise) farm.  Or that you do not have the set of language packs installed.  I do not know exactly how to determine whether a farm is enterprise or foundation via the database only.  You could look for hints such as Standard or Enterprise databases on the database server.

****EDIT********
[Use this link to download the SharePoint media with Service Pack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983).  14.0.7015.1000 is Service Pack 2.  You will need to uninstall the version of SharePoint that you have currently.

[Check this link for all the download links for the various build numbers.](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224)

Comment: Sorry I missed that you had a newer version installed.  Give me a minute and I'll look for a download link.

Comment: Got the same message after install this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24983 . 
I think it's the same version that I installed earlier.

Comment: I think you should try SharePoint Server instead of SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, James Grizzle. I tried to install the Share Point Server and the wizard asked me to install this version on database server too. Foundantion is the one. My problem is with the version (14.0.7015.1000). I need to run this specific version installer, or older, and run the patch - Considering that my problem is really with the version of the installed product.

Comment: Update: With ur link I was able to install the right version - thank you! -, but the error persists. Trying to overcome the situation I installed a new instance o Share Point, with a new config database, and I'm trying to change the config database to the original one. Is it possible? Setting the content db only seems not to be enough.

Comment: I do not believe there is anyway to change the configuration database.  Why is attaching the content databases to a new farm not enough?